# Vista - Program crash notification

Tags: .net, windows-vista

My memory is fuzzy but I seem to recall that Windows Vista introduced an ability to know why an application crashed. But I cannot remember the name of the feature.

My intent is that if my application crashed for some unknown reason, the next time it starts up I'd like to know why - or even just to know that it happened. Does anyone remember the name of this API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with such an API, but Windows Vista did introduce three major areas of functionality that might be what you're thinking of:

- [Application Recovery and Restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877200(VS.85).aspx)
- [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513635(VS.85).aspx)
- [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373649(VS.85).aspx)

If you're interested in knowing application crash details (e.g., exception code, faulting module, call stack, etc.) from deployed installations, I highly recommend signing up for a [Windows Error Reporting](https://winqual.microsoft.com/help/default.htm#about_windows_error_reporting_for_hardware.htm) (aka Winqual) account, then collecting and analyzing the crash data. You don't need to add any special diagnostic code to your application; the default unhandled exception code in the OS will automatically collect the appropriate data and send a report.